# Is it possible to store additional variables in a ratchet connection

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet

this is my `onMessage`

```
public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
    $tempMessage = json_decode($msg, TRUE);
    if ($tempMessage['type'] == 'online') {
        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            if ($client == $from) {
                echo "client " . $from->resourceId . "(" . $from->remoteAddress . ") is online\n";
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Is it possible to save values in this $client object for later reference?

i know it is possible to keep a array for this but it can get complicated
as in the documentation im storing the clients in a `SplObjectStorage`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## The Generic way

If you have a look at the [php documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/splobjectstorage.attach.php) for `\SplObjectStorage` you will see that you can add information to an object, so according to your code you can add the data like this

```php
$this->clients[$from]->setInfo(['myData' => 'foo']);
```

And then retrieve it like this

```php
$data   = $this->clients[$from]->getInfo();
var_dump($data); // $data = ['myData' => 'foo']
```

## The Easy/Fast way

***Disclaimer:*** this is only to set data in onOpen (eg: cookies), after that the connection is cloned everytime to be passed to onMessage making the original connection immutable, this is why I wouldn't recommend this solution to set data unrelated to the original connection, because it could lead to hard to debug bugs

> Since the connection is a php class you are allowed to add properties
> to it as long as the property is not already defined as protected or
> private
>
> In the source code of the client class (In
> `\Ratchet\AbstractConnectionDecorator`) you will find
>
> ```
> public function __set($name, $value) {
>     $this->wrappedConn->$name = $value;
> }
>
> public function __get($name) {
>     return $this->wrappedConn->$name;
> }
> ```
>
> Meaning the class is just a wrapper for a `\React\Socket\Connection`
> which has no setter/getter.

So you can manipulate the properties like you would on an object

```php
$client->myData = $data;
var_dump($client->myData);
```

## The alternative way

Instead of storing your clients in an `\SplObjectStorage` store them in a keyed array and use `spl_object_hash` to generate the key

*PS: This is already what's happening under the hood of SplObjectStorage so this is reinventing the wheel*

```php
/**
 * @var array[]
 */
protected $clients = [];

public function onOpen( ConnectionInterface $conn ) {
    $this->clients[spl_object_hash( $conn )] = [ 'connection' => $conn, 'myData' => "My data" ];
}

public function onMessage( ConnectionInterface $conn, $msg ) {
    $myData = $this->clients[spl_object_hash( $conn )]['myData'];
}
```